# C# - Checking device status in the background of a WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, background-process

I'm building a small WinForms application in C# that would interface with a barcode scanner and would allow me to check in / check out items labeled with a barcode by scanning the barcodes, performing an operation on them and then sending the info back to a central server. There are two things I want to be continuously checking though:

1. Is the barcode scanner connected to the device?
2. Is there network connection? If false, buffer data locally, if true, start transferring data to the central server if there is local data

There would also be an update to the GUI ("ONLINE"/"OFFLINE" message at the top, inability to use the GUI if no scanner is connected)

The way I could accomplish this is by using two BackgroundWorkers that continuously ran, polled for device status and reported back very often. I'm not sure if this "constant" use is the correct way of using the BackgroundWorker object though.

Are there better / cleaner ways of accomplishing these sorts of background checks in a C# WinForms App?

Comment: For WinForms, the BackgroundWorker is the preferred threading device.  It comes complete with mechanisms for reporting back status, completion, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scanner interface, it might be better to encapsulate the logic in one or more classes, and keep the device-level stuff away from the UI.

The same goes for the network connection monitor; that sounds complex enough to go into its own class.

If you're polling the hardware it might actually be better to use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to drive it rather than a `BackgroundWorker`.

Here's a sample console app which has a bare bones implentation where the logic is split up into separate classes.

The important thing to look at is the `Timer`, which drives it. It will call back periodically on a separate thread, from which it calls `poll()`. Note carefully that because it calls back in a separate thread, so you might need to use locking in some situations, and you mustn't call the UI directly from it.

For this simple class, a bool is being updated in an atomic operation so we don't need any synchronisation.

Hopefully you see what I mean about separating out the multithreaded logic into a separate class.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    // This represents the interface to the scanner hardware.

    sealed class BarcodeScannerDevice
    {
        int counter;

        public bool IsConnected()
        {
            return (++counter%4) != 0;  // Make it change every 4 calls.
        }
    }

    // This class has the responsibility of polling the scanner device to determine its status.

    sealed class BarcodeScannerMonitor
    {
        readonly Timer timer;
        readonly BarcodeScannerDevice scanner;

        bool isConnected;

        public BarcodeScannerMonitor(BarcodeScannerDevice scanner)
        {
            this.scanner = scanner;
            timer = new Timer(poll, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get
            {
                return isConnected;
            }
        }

        public void StopPolling()
        {
            timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        public void StartPolling(TimeSpan pollingInterval)
        {
            timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, pollingInterval);
        }

        void poll(object state)
        {
            isConnected = scanner.IsConnected();
        }
    }

    static class BarcodeScannerMonitorFactory
    {
        // You probably want to encapsulate this kind of coupling and 
        // keep it away from the UI, so we use a factory.

        public static BarcodeScannerMonitor Create()
        {
            var scanner = new BarcodeScannerDevice();
            return new BarcodeScannerMonitor(scanner);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            var scannerStatus = BarcodeScannerMonitorFactory.Create();
            scannerStatus.StartPolling(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scanner is " + (scannerStatus.IsConnected ? "connected" : "disconnected"));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that I haven't disposed the timer. Proper code should add to the `BarcodeScannerMonitor` class a `Dispose()` method which disposes the timer.

You might also want to make interfaces for the classes and use those in the UI instead, which can help with unit testing.

Finally, you might notice that Microsoft recommend using Windows Forms timers for Windows Forms programs, but I thing that for this kind of hardware polling a System.Threading.Timer is better.

Comment: I did not know a Timer could be used to run a method on a separate thread. Thanks for the info. However, what are the advantages of using a Timer over a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @RobinMattheussen The advantage is that it does not need a Window to operate, so you can encapsulate it in non-windows classes such as my example.

Answer (score 1):

I've used BackgroundWorkers for just this type of applications. BGWorkers are well suited to WinForm apps and they share the thread pool.  A BGWorker just abstracts the more granular Thread.  When you call RunWorkerAsync, the DoWork event is raised in the calling thread.  In your worker thread, it's permissible to invoke Sleep; if you're checking the status of instrument then something like every 1000 or 2000msec would likely work to report status and doesn't flood the GUI with events. Use the ReportProgress in you BGWorker to raise the ProgressChanged event in the GUI thread; you can pass data in the event args.  And when the thread completes, it raises the RunWorkerCompleted event.  You can explicitly stop the thread running by setting the CancellationPending property to true.

So that's the device side.  For a network connection being available, you could imagine the network is a device and use the same general strategy.  Off the top of my head, I'm not clear on what I'd use to 'ping' the network.

Comment: What would be the better way: putting a loop in the DoWork method of the BackGroundworker and reporting back every time you do a single run of the loop (via ReportProgress), or creating a loop dat runs the DoWork method again after it is finished (after RunWorkerCompleted)?